# Secure app using only jQuery and Web services?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, security, https

I was wondering if I can create all my future web apps using jQuery and webservices?  My thinking: Create all front-end using jQuery and css, and call web services for server side data.

My 2 questions:
1. My main concern is security:  For example, if I was creating a login page, is it safe enough to pass a user's credentials using HTTPS to call a authentication webservice?

1. Can anybody see what they think of this (good, bad) and any examples where jQuery and webservices would not suffice?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It is very rarely the language or technology which defines whether your method is secure -- it's your coding.  That said, you *can* use jQuery and web services, but how you do it is a very broad question.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, you really made my day!  At least I know it is possible.  I plan to research "Securing jQuery calls to webservice", do you have a better search term ?

Comment: Yes, don't search for it dependent on jQuery.  jQuery is a tool, what you want to know is how to do the task, then you can look at using the tool to perform those steps.  If you do it the other way, then you will only find what others have done using jQuery and be dependent on *their* quality of code.

Comment: I haven't built it for use in jQuery (I use jQuery everywhere), but [SRP](http://srp.stanford.edu/) is where I am taking all of my authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, is search term "Securing webservice" better?  In your experience, have you seen developers that create full web apps (login, register, forms) using only jQuery and webservices?  Is this pretty common?

Comment: Not sure on the search term, but to be honest, comments are for clarifying the question, not for chat.  I bet if you search "web login security" on here you'll find a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your time Jeremy, if you have any other comments or opinions please share.